# The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(TitleLayout) is undefined

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have created a titile_layout.xml, and i want to use TitleLayout into Mainactivity. But when i create a AlertDialog when i press a button, there is a error as below. i think maybe is there something wrong with "TitleLayout.this"? but if i do not use it, what should i use? why?

```
package cn.example.uilayouttest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TitleLayout extends LinearLayout  {

    public TitleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.title_layout, TitleLayout.this);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // The wrong is here:The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(TitleLayout) is undefined
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(TitleLayout.this);
                ad.setTitle("fefsfs");
                ad.setMessage("fefwefw");
                ad.setPositiveButton("fefw", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                ad.show();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }
//  public void onclick ()

}
```

Comment: Because `TitleLayout`  is not a `Activity`. You need to use a `Context` of `TitleLayout` making its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is a Context object. Change

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(TitleLayout.this);
```

with

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```

or mark the Context's object of the constructor as final and use it

```
 public TitleLayout(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 

 /// other code

 new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Thanks! i use getContext(). it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

`Your Activity exetends LinearLayout`, So it does not provide any context, `context` is actually related to your current page, like `this` keyword.

**Simply use**

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```